# Start multiple independent functions with a single global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, variables, global-variables

I'm sure I'm thinking about this wrong, but I can't quite figure out how to get out of my dead end.

I'm building a program to flash LEDs independently based on an outside input.  The code I have works for a single LED.  However, every way I can think of to make it work for multiple LEDs seems dumb.

Basically, I want all of the instances of the function to start with the same global variables, but then go on their own merry way once they get cooking.  Here's the relevant part of the current code:

```
counter = 0
time_from_start = 0
new_average = 0

#eventually this will be get_new_average(sensor_number)
def get_new_average():
    #average is going to be time in .... ms?
    #eventually it will be the average from the arduino
    new_average = int(input("new average? "))

def lighter_up(light_number, intensity):
    print("lighter_up intensity = " + str(intensity))
    #this line needs to be modified to whatever the intensity should be
    strip.setPixelColorRGB(light_number, intensity, 0, 0)
    strip.show()
    return intensity + 1

def lighter_down(light_number, intensity):
    print("lighter_down value = " + str(255 - (intensity - 255)))
    #this line needs to be modified to whatever the intensity should be
    strip.setPixelColorRGB(light_number, 255 - (intensity - 255), 0, 0)
    strip.show()
    return intensity + 1

def heartbeat(light):
    #acknowledge that counter is a global variable
    global counter
    global start_time

    if counter == 0:
        get_new_average()
        #this counts seconds from an arbitrary start point
        start_time = int(time.perf_counter())
        counter = 1
    #the 255 value is arbitrary
    #need to change it when you figure out the flash
    elif 0 < counter < 255:
        counter = lighter_up(light, counter)
    elif 254 < counter <510:
        counter = lighter_down(light, counter)
    elif counter > 509:
        #turn off the light
        strip.setPixelColorRGB(light, 0, 0, 0)
        strip.show()
        #difference between the start time and now
        time_from_start = int(time.perf_counter()) - start_time
        print(time_from_start)
        #if the time from the start of the flash is less than the
        #duration of the heartbeat, as defiend by new_average
        if time_from_start < new_average:
            #just wait it out
            pass
        #if the time from start has hit the new_average
        #it is time for a new heartbeat
        elif time_from_start >= new_average:
            counter = 0
        else:
            print("There was an error in heartbeat()")
    else:
        print("error: counter = " + str(counter))
while True:
    heartbeat(0)
```

I want to add a `heartbeat(1)` to the end to control a second light that will eventually be attached to the second sensor.  However, doing so will make the 'counter' from heartbeat(0) and the 'counter' from heartbeat(1) conflict (and will have the same effect on time_from_start and new_average).

I could create a list of global variables ('counter0', 'counter1', etc) but that seems dumb and inelegant.  I could also move counter inside of heartbeat(), but then it just resets to zero every time it loops and nothing will ever happen.  There must be a better way!

I strongly suspect (hope?) that this is a totally common python thing with a deeply obvious solution.  I just can't find it.  Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're looking for is a way to have distinct sets of variables `counter`, `time_from_start` and `new_average` for each "light", so you can apply your functions to each light independently without functions overwriting the other "lights"'s own set of variables ?

If yes, the pythonic solution is to define a class and create one instance per light. Your functions then become methods of the class, and each instance has it's own state (set of variable):

```
class Light(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
       self.number = number
       self.counter = 0
       self.time_from_start = 0
       self.new_average = 0

    def get_new_average(self):
        self.new_average = int(input("new average? "))

    def lighter_up(self, intensity):
        print("lighter_up intensity = " + str(intensity))
        #this line needs to be modified to whatever the intensity should be
        strip.setPixelColorRGB(self.number, intensity, 0, 0)
        strip.show()
        return intensity + 1

    def lighter_down(light_number, intensity):
        print("lighter_down value = " + str(255 - (intensity - 255)))
        #this line needs to be modified to whatever the intensity should be
        strip.setPixelColorRGB(self.number, 255 - (intensity - 255), 0, 0)
        strip.show()
        return intensity + 1

    def heartbeat(self):
        if self.counter == 0:
            self.get_new_average()
            #this counts seconds from an arbitrary start point
            start_time = int(time.perf_counter())
            self.counter = 1

        #the 255 value is arbitrary
        #need to change it when you figure out the flash
        elif 0 < self.counter < 255:
            self.counter = self.lighter_up(self.counter)
        elif 254 < self.counter <510:
            self.counter = self.lighter_down(self.counter)
        elif counter > 509:
            #turn off the light
            strip.setPixelColorRGB(light, 0, 0, 0)
            strip.show()
            #difference between the start time and now
            self.time_from_start = int(time.perf_counter()) - start_time
            print(self.time_from_start)
            #if the time from the start of the flash is less than the
            #duration of the heartbeat, as defiend by new_average
            if self.time_from_start < self.new_average:
                #just wait it out
                pass
            #if the time from start has hit the new_average
            #it is time for a new heartbeat
            elif self.time_from_start >= self.new_average:
                self.counter = 0
            else:
                print("There was an error in heartbeat()")
        else:
            print("error: counter = " + str(self.counter))


lights = [Light(0), Light(1)]
while True:
   for light in lights:
       light.heartbeat()
```

Comment: Thanks! I a tingling sensation that this was the type of problem that classes are designed to address but wasn't quite sure how to turn that into action.  I guess my python world just got a bit  more complex.

Comment: Well actually you could solve the problem without classes - using a list of `{"counter":XXX, "new_average": XXX,  "time_from_start": XXX}` dicts (instead of a list of `Light` instances) and passing those dicts to your functions (so they would use `lightdict["counter"]` etc instead of globals), but yes, that's _one_ of the problems that classes where designed to address.